# Angular change detection in array: IterableDiffers vs change array reference?

Tags: angular

In my Angular project I have several arrays that contain some data such as object references and simple types.

I see two approaches to detecting changes in my arrays.

IterableDiffers seems to be the more correct way to do this, but changing an array reference feels faster and easier.

By the **IterableDiffers** approach, I mean checking in the `ngDoCheck` hook.

By the **changing an array reference** approach, I mean using `slice()` or `[].concat(arr)` methods.

What should I use in this situation and in general?

Also, is the second approach a bad practice?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered `rxjs` , making your data a `behaviorSubject` or just a `subject` and subscribe to it?

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov hes correct, I would also strongly recommend looking into this and maybe  google a bit, for example about facade patterns ( my favorite ) 


example obsevable, and when subscribint to data$, it would automatically detect changes on your state property. Also it can be just separate property. 
 readonly data$ = this.state.pipe(map(({ data}) => data), distinctUntilChanged());

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov, thank you! This approach looks really nice!

Comment: @DevyDev, thank you! This approach looks really nice! And I found the facade pattern very useful. [Sorry for double comment, but I can't cast more than one personal in one message]